# Python: Delete an Object if it's bellow a certain Z Coordinate

Tags: python

I need a python scrip that takes an object, moves it down, separates it into loose parts, sets the origins to geometry and deletes 1 object that is left bellow Z=0. So far I've cobbled toguether this code from different posts but when it comes to selecting the lower object all the results I get are talking about vertices and not objects themselves. Can anyone help me with this?
At the end of this code all the objects are already selected and not in a specific collection so maybe deselecting anything above Z=0 would work better before deleting the last object.
The code shouldn't affect non selected objects in the scene, not sure if that's relevant

```
import bpy

#Move down
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0.0, 0.0, -20.0), orient_type='GLOBAL')

# Separate the selected objects by disconnected geometry
bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type="LOOSE")

# Get the selected objects
separated_obj_names = [obj.name for obj in bpy.context.view_layer.objects.selected]

#origins to geometry
bpy.ops.object.origin_set(
    type='ORIGIN_GEOMETRY',
    center='MEDIAN')
```

Comment: `for o in bpy.context.selected_objects[:]: if o.location.z < 0: bpy.data.objects.remove(o)`

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly